# Troublesome bug Chrome Developer tools in last update. How can I avoid it?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, clipboard

So, Chrome released a new version of its browser (v95.0.4638.54) adding a new feature than not only I can't use. Its bugged and also cause me a lot of trouble when I'm developing...

This new feature adds the option to change the type of units in dimension. Like for example, from 3px to 3em, 3cm, 3%...
I don't really see the point on this, but guess that could be useful for someone if they added that.

So the first and less important problem is that I can't use this feature, cause it uses white background even if you use dark theme and your font is white too...

[That's how it looks for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7Gc2.png)

And now **THE REAL TROUBLE**. It seems that they didn't tested how it works... It just... It didn't work... Lets say for example that I defined this styles with the Dev Tools:

```
color: white;
padding: 2em 0 0 2em;
border-radius: 0 0 1em 1em;
```

When I try to copy the text and paste it on any IDE or text editor, that's what I get now:

```
    color: white;
    padding: 2
em
  0 0 2
em
;
    border-radius: 0 0 1
em
  1
em
;
```

So...
Downgrade my browser before this bug is not an option, I have to see what I develop on last version.

1. There's some online tool or light program to format the copied text until Chrome fix their bug? I don't want to format the whole document for a few lines.
2. There's some Chrome extension or way to avoid the bug without changing the Chrome version?
3. Is there a way to automatically modify my clipboard to paste something at least less disturbing?

Comment: If you're working on vscode, there is a shortcut to format the document (`Shift` + `Alt` + `f`) or the selected line if you don't want to format the entire document

Comment: It's a bug in devtools, https://crbug.com/1259088, fixed in Canary.

Comment: Waiting for a fix...
And the possibility to change the unit is completely useless and painful when you want change the value.

Comment: @polypode what CSS formatter will be able to fix those linebreaks? i didn't find any formatted that is fixing `2 px ;` to `2px;`

Answer (score 1):

This feature is reverted in v96 which was published today (nov 15).

I Assume they will test it properly before pushing it in the next version, though I don't see the use of this feature at all